# Unhandled exception in _mm_extract_si64 API call using VS 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intel, msdn, intrinsics

Using Visual C++ 2017 version, the following sample code (as given in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384811.aspx ) is running with unhandled exception.

```
// Compile this sample with: /EHsc  
#include <iostream>  
#include <intrin.h>  
using namespace std;  

union {  
    __m128i m;  
    unsigned __int64 ui64[2];  
} source, descriptor, result1, result2, result3;  

int  
main()  
{  
    source.ui64[0] =     0xfedcba9876543210ll;  
    descriptor.ui64[0] = 0x0000000000000b1bll;  

    result1.m = _mm_extract_si64 (source.m, descriptor.m);  // here unhandled-exception occurs
    result2.m = _mm_extracti_si64(source.m, 27, 11);  
    result3.ui64[0] = (source.ui64[0] >> 11) & 0x7ffffff;  

    cout << hex << "result1 = 0x" << result1.ui64[0] << endl;  
    cout << "result2 = 0x" << result2.ui64[0] << endl;  
    cout << "result3 = 0x" << result3.ui64[0] << endl;  
}
```

I am running this using VS 2017 on windows 7 Ultimate and Intel Core i3 4030U processor.
What's wrong in here? How to resolve? Please suggest.

Comment: Using global variables for getting data into / out of `__m128i` seems like a terrible idea.  But what is the exception, and which source line / asm instruction throws it?

Comment: Those intrinsics are not part of the Intel documentation, and only work some non-Intel (AMD) CPUs that support them (SSE4a).  There is a paragraph in the Remarks section of your linked documentation that explains how to see if they are supported on your CPU.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for SSE4.1 [`_mm_extract_epi64`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=pextrq&expand=2290)?  Or a shuffle like AVX2 `vpermq` to select an element?